# computer vision distance btw pixels

Tags: python, opencv

Hello everyone please i need help to find distance in number of pixels between two pixels(with coordinates) in image
thanks in advance

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
%matplotlib inline``
``
img = cv.imread('building.jpg',-1)
cv.imshow('image',img)
 # to display image until you press any key
cv.waitKey(0)
 # to destroy all windows
cv.destroyAllWindows()
pixels = np.array(img)
width, height, channels = pixels.shape
print(width)
print (height)
P=img[200,510]
print (P)
Q=img[100,410]
print (Q)``
```

Comment: Sorry but I could not get the intension of your question. Please consider to make the example simpler(there seems to be unnecessary `import` etc..). If these 2 points are the ones which you want to measure, why don't you use Pythagorean theorem? `math.sqrt(100*100+100*100)`

Answer (score 1):

I have used this function to calculate distance:

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**(1/2)

point1 = (200, 510)
point2 = (100, 410)

distance(point1[0], point1[1],
         point2[0], point2[1])
```

Output:

```
141.4213562373095
```

Comment: thank you for your help but  is it in number of pixels

Comment: yes, that is number of pixels diagonally, if you convert it to int

Comment: can you make the answer the solution? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use scipy for this task.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
pt1 = (100, 100)
pt2 = (200, 200)
dist = euclidean (pt1, pt2)
# if want in int then use 
#dist = int(dist)
```